# Check if flash movie is done playing

Tags: vb.net, flash

I have flash movies that were converted from powerpoints using a powerpoint converter. I can play the flash movies, but I need to determine if the movie is at the end or done playing.

I need to hide the flash movie control and display some controls after the flash movie. I tried researching but found no solid answer, just some code segments that does not work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Here's how I play my video:

```
    AxShockwaveFlash1.Stop()
    AxShockwaveFlash1.Movie = Application.StartupPath & "\RSA.swf"
    AxShockwaveFlash1.Play()
    AxShockwaveFlash1.Loop = False
```

I used iSpring to convert the powerpoint to a flash movie.

Comment: Please describe/show us how you are playing the movies. If you wrote your own player (using NetConnection/NetStream) you can listen for an event from the NetStream. If you are using someone else's player, then the answer will likely vary.

Comment: Thank you for the notice. I updated my post as to what you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article on [checking the length of a SWF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/4cfd1944-9dcd-4156-acfe-cdaea3046785/) (movie clip?). It describes a technique you can use with the `AxShockwaveFlash` object to figure out if the SWF is on it's last frame.

There are other techniques you can do, but you generally need to modify the code for the SWF to dispatch an event or call a function at the end of the movie clip.

I wish I could be of more help, but alas, Microsoft doesn't seem to make the API reference for `AxShockwaveFlash` available on the web (perhaps b/c I don't subscribe to MSDN).

Comment: I already saw and used this but the code seems to process every time tick. So it really doesn't get the last frame, just incrementing the variables every time tick.

Comment: That code gets the frame count from the SWF after it dispatches a "ready" event. Then on every timer tick, yes, it tries to figure out if the end was reached. Unless you modify the SWF and make it communicate when the end is reached, there is no other solution than to use a timer. You might want to edit your question and further show/explain what you've already tried.